# JBoss ticket-monster example questions

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss

I have latest Jboss installed and I am going through its [ticket-monster tutorial](http://www.jboss.org/jdf/examples/ticket-monster/tutorial/Introduction/) step by step but stuck at the Deployment stage. I am using windows 7.

The **Run on Server** executed successfully. **Welcome To JBoss!** page was displayed. I have copied the h2console.war into the **deployments** folder of the JBoss installation. But the **h2console** page refused to come out. I tried many times. Any comments will be appreciated.

Another question is the tutorial says:

**If needed, this will startup the application server instance, compile & build the application and push the application into the JBOSS_HOME/standalone/deployments directory.**

But I cannot find the ticket-monster war or other war on the **deployments** folder. h2console.war is the only war file there. Is this correct?

The error message is this:

```
JBWEB000065: HTTP Status 404 - /h2console

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

JBWEB000309: type JBWEB000067: Status report

JBWEB000068: message /h2console

JBWEB000069: description JBWEB000124: The requested resource is not available.


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

JBoss Web/7.2.2.Final-redhat-1
```

---

#### Solved

I was thinking the JBoss I installed before I installed  jbdevstudio was used. But the jbdevstudio contains a runtime JBoss which is used from the jbdevstudio by default.